# Many to one Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

So, here'e the situation:

Table `ComputerInventory` with `{computerInventoryID (Primary key), TagID(unique), Name etc}`

Table `reviewStatus` with `{reviewStatusID(Primary key), computerInventoryID (ForeignKey), status }`

I've written the hibernate Entity for `ReviewStatus`:

```
public class ReviewStatus implements Serializable {

public enum reviewStatus {
    To_Be_Reviewed,
    Reviewed
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long reviewStatusId;
@Column(name = "lastModifiedTime")
private Date lastModifiedTime;
@Column(name = "Comments")
private String comments;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
//all above params have gettetrs and setters
private reviewStatus status;
//TODO: Mapping to computerinventory
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "computerInventoryId")
//For one ComputerInventoryID, there can be many review Statuses.
private Set<ReviewStatus> reviewStatusSet;

public long getreviewStatusId() {
    return reviewStatusId;
}
```

My Doubts:
For one ComputerInventoryID, there can be many review Statuses, so do I have a

```
Set<ReviewStatus> reviewStatusSet
```

where I return the list of entries in reviewstatus? Sorry, but I don't understand how I can write a get/set for returning and setting the reviews status of a bunch of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference from ReviewStatus should be to a ComputerInventory, not to its ID.  Hibernate lets you abstract out the details of the primary key (the ID), letting you directly reference from one object to another.  You should use an `@ManyToOne` annotation on your `private ComputerInventory computerInventory;`.